# Sound control in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer

If I add two `Fragment` to one `Activity`, each playing different media, is there a way to mute the sound coming from one `Fragment` while the other plays full volume?

From my research, it seems you can only control the devices volume with code, thus if two media are playing, they'll inherit the same volume.

Any idea about getting around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set volume for every mediaplayer. [api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float))

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I'll see if I can make it work for my purposes.